# My rake task is not showing up in rake -T

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rake-task

I don't know wtf is going on but I just created a new Rails app and can't get any rake tasks to work or show up in `$ rake -T`

lib/tasks/hello.rake

```
namespace :hello do 
  desc "hello"
  task :you do 
    puts "hello"
  end
end
```

`$ rake -T`

it does not show up in there

`$ rake hello:you`

> rake aborted!
>   Don't know how to build task 'hello:you' (see --tasks)

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.2'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

gem 'carrierwave', github: 'carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave'
gem 'mini_magick',             '3.8.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

Comment: Confirm that you haven't used a different extension (e.g. `hello.rb`).

Comment: no i am using rake extension.

Comment: I hope u have saved the file after writing the task as there doesn't seem any syntax error. Also tried restarting the terminal?

Comment: Also try running `rake hello:you --trace` to see full trace (and add it to your question).

Comment: @Gerry You the man. Easy mistake to make. Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you want a really complete list of all rake tasks, you need to run
`rake -T -A`.

Comment: -A Show all tasks, even uncommented ones. So the real problem is that the task is missing a comment. The task is shown in the list as soon as you add a description for it as @aardvarkk explained.

Answer (score 46):

It could be that you've given the task the `.rb` extension instead of `.rake`

Comment: It's an easy mistake to make. One I've made a couple of times since writing this answer!

Comment: You're a genius! :)

Answer (score 17):

I had this problem, but it was due to the fact that I hadn't provided a description for my task. Once I added `desc 'Hello World'` above my `task` block, the task showed up in the list.

Comment: Yup. That did it.

Answer (score 2):

My solution was that I had the incorrect directory. I created custom tasks under  `Rails.root/app/lib/tasks` when it should have been `Rails.root/lib/tasks`.

Only realized this after running the command `bin/rails generate task` as per the [Rails guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#custom-rake-tasks).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a default Rakefile with:

```rb
# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.

require_relative "config/application"

Rails.application.load_tasks
```

After this `rake -T` seemed to return my task defined under `lib/tasks`

Another possibly similar issue: [Rake -T does not identify tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73289531/rake-t-does-not-identify-tasks/77456129#77456129)