# Rake -T does not identify tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I am trying to setup a Rake Task (without rails), and thus created a demo Hello World Task. However, upon running `rake -T` or `rake --tasks` nothing is returned, as if the task hasn't been identified. What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

Also When I run `rake hello_world` I get the following error:

```bash
➜  ~/GitHub/Cerner/test git:(master) ✗ rake hello_world
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'hello_world' (See the list of available tasks with `rake --tasks`)
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/rake-13.0.6/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/hsbagga28/gems/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
/home/hsbagga28/gems/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

[Update] The rakefile:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.
$LOAD_PATH.push File.expand_path('lib', __dir__)
```

Comment: Show your `Rakefile`, please (just please share code, not images)

Comment: I have made the update in the question.

Comment: "[Update] The rakefile" - no, Konstantin meant the file called `Rakefile`. It should be in the project root.

Comment: Oh! Sorry My Bad. I have made the edits again

Comment: @imharjyotbagga your Rakefile looks like it was copy-pasted from some other project (probably a Rails one). `$LOAD_PATH` has no effect in your case (at least, not the one you expect). By default, besides the task defined in the Rakefile itself, Rake loads tasks from `rakelib` directory that is a sibling to `Rakefile` itself (if the former exists). You can change this via `--rakelibdir` parameter or simply load the tasks definitions explicitly from the `Rakefile`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a default Rakefile with:

```rb
# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.

require_relative "config/application"

Rails.application.load_tasks
```

After this `rake -T` seemed to return my task defined under `lib/tasks`